# The Complexity of dom manipulation in React + Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to simplify the workflow when using React and Redux.

For basic DOM Manipulation tasks like scrolling an element down or performing a check for something in an interval, you have to declare many functions and all of a sudden you may have 100 lines of code when there should only be a few lines of code.

The following example is with the react-redux starter kit. Using helper modules such as

**createAction, handleActions**

The task performed is basicly

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("id");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

First we have to set our action type in the *module*

```
export const SCROLL_DOWN = 'SCROLL_DOWN'
```

Then we have to define the action for scrolling down

```
export const setScrollDown = createAction(SCROLL_DOWN, (setScrollDown = true) => setScrollDown)
```

Then the reducer, where we set the state hasScrolledDown which in turn has to be defined in the module we're in.

```
export default handleActions({
  [SCROLL_DOWN]: (state, { payload }) => {
    return {
      ...state, hasScrolledDown: payload
    }
  }
}, {hasScrolledDown: false})
```

Next we have to use all of this in the View

We define the propTypes

```
class MessagesView extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    setScrollDown: PropTypes.func,
    hasScrolledDown: PropTypes.bool
  };
```

And finally we use them in the componentDidMount & componentDidUpdate functions, to manipulate the dom we need to import the react-dom module, so that goes at the top of the document.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

And then we're finally able to scroll down the page.

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.props.setScrollDown(false)
}

componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
  if (!this.props.hasScrolledDown) {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).scrollIntoView(false)
    this.props.setScrollDown(true)
  }
}
```

So, my question is: Am i going about this the wrong way, or is there a simple solution to handle simple dom-manipulation like this?

As you would imagine when having a large application where you need to perform basic dom-manipulation tasks like this here and there, the codebase grows quite fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For DOM stuff like this, like scrolling to a certain point, doing the whole Redux state/action/reducer thing is a bit of an overkill. Of course, this all comes down to personal preference, but there's no need to make things more complicated than they are.

Not knowing your entire application, I'm just making assumptions here, but imagine that your page has a button or something which sole purpose is to scroll the user back to the top of the window. This is something Redux or React shouldn't need to care about, so leveraging it to plain old javascript is a heck of a lot easier to figure about. The way to go about this would usually involve `componentDidMount`, add a click listener to the button, and take care of the scrolling there.

I even use this approach on tooltips and other GUI stuff that I don't need in a persistent state, because usually it doesn't make sense. Redux is great for keeping track of application state, but that doesn't mean you are forced into using it for every little thing that you don't have to be able to reproduce at any given time.

Comment: I think a lot of people tend to fall into the trap of putting _everything_ in their store when they start using Redux - I know I did.

Comment: @JoeClay We all have :) I was constantly looking for best practice info on where I should store this and that, but at the end of the day we are using these tools to make life easier on ourselves. Theoretically at least...

Comment: It just seems like the correct way to go about it. But if i want the view to automatically scroll down after it has finished rendering, a button wont solve that problem?

Comment: @JazzCat you could try doing that within `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: @JazzCat Then put your scroll logic in `componentDidUpdate`. The question that needs answering is "Does this scroll affect other parts of my application?" If no, then don't bother with the Redux pipeline for that functionality.

Comment: Still have to use ReactDOM & tamper with the dom that way, and if i have something thats modifying the state in an interval. Woops, im scrolled up every time the interval ticks.

Comment: Combine it with some control variable. While it's not encouraged, it's still ok to use the component's internal state even if you use Redux. At least that's what its maker says: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/623097205386293248